# How to recover a Gmail account after changing the password?

Tags: gmail

I have changed my Gmail password, and I can not recover it.
I have the Old password, which was working fine.
I have lost my account data.
I have changed my phone number.
The alternative email have been closed by server provider(I do not sign in for long time).
So, I tried several things, all failed, but I have found a software called "Gmail Account Password Hacker", Can I trust and install it?

Comment: I wouldn't trust such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use any password crackers or something like this. It is not safe and the chance to get your password is nearly zero if it's not a password like '12345' or 'hello'.

Instead try the regular password recovery. If you follow the questions there should be options to recover the account with an old password and some additional information.
https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/

Comment: +1 Google's account recovery options are very thorough with several methods to recover an account. I managed to do this successfully with a friend, with surprisingly little concrete information, however, it did require us to attempt recovery from the same machine/location (IP address/ISP) from which we had previously logged in successfully - which I think was the key in our case.